# C - OpenSSL with AES-256 and CFB mode

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, cryptography, aes

I am working on Ubuntu 14.10 and I am trying to get the same output using C and OpenSSL that I would get using the command:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cfb8 -in test -out test.enc -K $key -iv $iv
```

I have been working on this for two days and not getting it, the encryption works but it is not the one I am supposed to get.

My code is:

```
int outlen, inlen;  

unsigned char inbuf[BUFSIZE] , outbuf[BUFSIZE];  

strcpy(inbuf,text);

EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;   
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);   

EVP_EncryptInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_aes_256_cfb8(), NULL, key, iv);

int i =0;
int n = strlen(text);
for(i; i < n; i++) {    

    if(!EVP_EncryptUpdate(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen, inbuf, 1)) 
        return 0;  
}    

if(!EVP_EncryptFinal(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen)) 
    return 0;  

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx); P_EncryptFinal(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen)) 
    return 0;  

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);  i < n; i++) {    

    if(!EVP_EncryptUpdate(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen, inbuf, 1)) 
        return 0;  
}    

if(!EVP_EncryptFinal(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen)) 
    return 0;  

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are encrypting the same byte over and over again. In EVP_EncryptUpdate, you have to move the inbuf pointer along across each input byte, and you have to move the outbuf pointer along to fresh memory. I made minor changes to your code (and completed it enough to run):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

#define BUFSIZE 256

int doit(char* text, char* key, char* iv)
{
    int outlen, inlen;  

    unsigned char inbuf[BUFSIZE] , outbuf[BUFSIZE];  

    strcpy(inbuf,text);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;   
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);   

    EVP_EncryptInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_aes_256_cfb8(), NULL, key, iv);

    int i =0;
    int n = strlen(text);
    unsigned char* p = outbuf;
    for(i; i < n; i++) {    

        if(!EVP_EncryptUpdate(&ctx, p, &outlen, &inbuf[i], 1)) 
            return 0;  
        p += outlen;
    }    

    if(!EVP_EncryptFinal(&ctx, p, &outlen)) 
        return 0;  
    p += outlen;

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);

    outlen = p - outbuf;
    for (n = 0; n < outlen; n++)
        printf("%c", outbuf[n] & 0xff);
}

int main()
{
    char* key = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
    char* iv = "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB";
    doit("hello world", key, iv);
}
```

The C code wants bytes for key and IV, but the openssl command line wants hex chars. This command line will get you the same result as the above C code:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cfb8 -in test -out test.enc -K 4141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141 -iv 42424242424242424242424242424242
```

Of course, you need to set up the exact same plaintext:

```
$ echo "hello world" > test
$ truncate --size 11 test # remove newline at end
```

Comment: It worked!!! and I was also able to do the decryption based on that one. But I am not understanding something about the bufsize. Working with bufsize = 256 it did not work for other strings like "abcdefghijklm", I had to increase it to 512, so what is bufsize representing and how should I choose the size of it? Is it possible to determine it during the execution base on the text to code?

Comment: Update -- I am not sure what I was doing wrong but it is all working now with the right bufsize and I would say that it is the number of "elements" my initial and final string are going to have.